# Redirect to new page from Server for ASP.Net MVC Ajax Request

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to call a method from another controller using `RedirectToAction()`. But it doesn't work. Could you please explain, what I'm doing wrong?

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddToWishList(int id, bool check)
{
    var currentUser = WebSecurity.CurrentUserId;
    if (currentUser != -1)
    {
        // ...              
    }
    else
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
    }            
}
```

I call the method in HTML:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    /* call the method in case the user selects a checkbox */
    $("#checkbox".concat(@Model.Id)).change(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("AddToWishList", "Item")',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                id: '@Model.Id',
                check: this.checked
            }
        });
    });
});
```

It works if I use:

```
success: function (result) {
    window.location.href = "@Url.Content("~/Account/Login")";
}
```

But I don't need to navigate to the Login() after every click, only if the user is not authorized. Could you please explain how I can use redirect in the controller?

Comment: Ajax posts are async and must be redirected using JavaScript.  You can't make a post request via ajax and have the server endpoint navigate the browser to a new window.

Comment: why don't you try putting your if @model.id != -1 before you run your $("#checkbox")...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can response ***[JavaScript](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.javascript.aspx)*** which basically returns ***[JavaScriptResult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.javascriptresult.aspx)***.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddToWishList(int id, bool check)
{
    return JavaScript("window.location='/Account/Login'");
}
```

Comment: @KarlGjertsen what's the problem? This answer returns an `ActionResult`, in MVC.

Comment: @KarlGjertsen Not a problem. I updated the answer to make it clear.

Answer (score 0):

To add to @Win's answer - I had a use case where I had a legacy ASPX file in my ASP.NET MVC application. And, I had to navigate to that ASPX page from my MVC action returning `ActionResult`. So, I did something like this to navigate to that ASPX page from my action. I had to create an absolute URL for navigation.

```
var myLegacyPageUrl = Request.Url.Scheme 
                                   + "://"
                                   + Request.Url.Authority
                                   + Url.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.ApplicationPath
                                   + "/mylegacypage.aspx?";
                return JavaScript(string.Format("window.location='{0}'", errorPageUrl));
```

Hope someone finds it useful in case of legacy web pages present in modern MVC website.