# Return Response.Redirect or ActionResult from a single MVC method

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a *MVC* method that currently returns an **ActionResult** - I have had to make some changes and based on the business logic I want to do a response.redirect instead.

So I want to do something like this:

```
public ActionResult Index(CountryHomePageType currentPage)
{
     if (someVar = true)
     {              
         return View();
     }
     else
     {
        Response.redirect("www.website.com")
     }
}
```

but I can't becuase Resonse.Redirect is not a ActionResult....

How can I get round this?

Comment: You are redirectiing outside of your website?

Comment: Related post - [Redirect to new page from Server for ASP.Net MVC Ajax Request](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40851111/465053)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are redirecting outside of your current mvc application you can use

```
return Redirect("<your external url>"); // like "https://www.google.com"
```

if you want to redirecto back you your homepage you can use

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

assuming you are using the default mvc setup

You might want to also look at [ActionFilters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs) if you are making this check in multiple places.

Comment: the compiler didn't recognize "Redirect" but it did recognize RedirectResult(url) - I'm guessing this is a MVC version issue?

Comment: @AyoAdesina What version are you using?  You tagged it with 3,4,5.  The code I posted is using mvc5 and Redirect exists.